# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity 2.0 & OWIN Two Factor Authentication by using existing DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, two-factor-authentication

I've just started with MVC after working on Web Forms for 4 years. I've watched few videos explaining the architecture/fundamentals and I'm now able to replicate few modules of my old project with MVC5 using EF6.

I've a SQL Server DB containing tables such as Albums/Artists/Titles/Reviews and he User Table. I was able to work with the first set of tables using EF6 just fine including inserts/deletes. The prev project I had implemented custom Web Forms authentication using BCrypt by storing the details in the User table and later doing the validations and setting the auth cookie.

User table has details such as UserId, PWHash, EMail, FirstName, LastName. The UserId is a FK in the Reviews table and few others.

The implementation I'm hoping for is as below:

```
  1. Login screen accepts credentials and validates with existing User table.
  2. If valid, move to the 2FA screen(eMail/SMS).
  3. If valid, then allow access to application.
```

Most of the tutorials say how to extend the attributes such as FirstName/LastName but do not say how to use an existing DB. I'm planning to use bcrypt/scrypt to encrypt the sensitive details.

I've gone through [MVC 5 & ASP.NET Identity - Implementation Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385582/mvc-5-asp-net-identity-implementation-confusion) but id doesn't have all the answers to my queries

I just need the starting point on how to plug the existing DB instead of using the dbcontext provided by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is using EF Code First then you can use your existing schema and plug in your own user. Look at the following example which shows how you can reuse your existing user information and plug it into Identity http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/CustomMembershipSample/Readme.txt

You do not have to inherit from the IdentityDbContext. You can directly use the DbContext. In this case you will have to override the onModelCreating to create the Users/ Roles tables and all the mappings between the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find the documentation quite frustrating as well when you move away from th conventional, so you may be in for a world of pain.

The easiest way would be to fully take control of the authentication process yourself, utilising [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, if you want to leverage a lot of the out the box code, that has been delivered with MVC5 but against a custom database, or schema you will probably have to implement your own UserStore and maybe [UserManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) among other things.

The problem is, there is a lot to implement, so you are going to have a fun time guaranteed.

Have a read through this article on [Custom Storage Prodivers](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) to get a head start.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look and update you if I get stuck somewhere.