# ASP.Net Identity 2 Manage Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Looking for a way to implement a simple system administrator page for managing identity 2 users. I would like to simply select the list of all users and roles and then bind the list to an editable control such as a GridView.

Easy with regular datasets however the mechanics of the User Manager classes and methods are getting in the way of something which would otherwise be fairly easy.

Seems like a common task but searched everywhere but found no helpful samples. FYI, this solution is designed for a small group of in-house users only, it's not designed for self-registration or external validation by Facebook etc.

Comment: this post is helpful for you;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385582/mvc-5-asp-net-identity-implementation-confusion/30511153#30511153