# Navigate inside entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, action-filter

I have a web-site with many entities, all these entities are linked to company. User, which logged to site, has a linked company too, so, he sees only entities, linked to his company. Also, there is a admin, who can works with all companies, he selects a company and then navigate inside site like simple user. I think what is the best way to pass this company id to select entities. Of course, I can add CompanyId to each method in each controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? CompanyId)
    {
         //.....
    }
```

and create Action Filter like this:

```
public class CompanyIdValueActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Superadmin") && filterContext.HttpContext.Request["CompanyId"] != null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and mark by this attribute each method and add to each link parameter CompanyId, but probably it can be a more effective and flexible way?

Answer (score 0):

Since the CompanyID is associated to the user, if you're using any recent asp.net technology, just add the CompanyId as a claim of the user (claims should be available).

[An Introduction to Claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359101.aspx)

[Access Claim values in controller in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246538/access-claim-values-in-controller-in-mvc-5)

Comment: I understand for users, associated to company, I mean access for superadmin, which selected company for short-time...

Comment: I don't see how it would be any different.  Add the claim to the super user.. now they are in said company.