# OWIN identity roles work locally, but seem to disappear when I publish/run the same code on a remote IIS server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, claims-based-identity

Using an OWIN [AuthenticationHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn253815(v=vs.113).aspx) within an MVC site, I sign in a user as follows:

```
var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, UIRoles.PowerUser) };
var identity = session.ToClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, claims);
Context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```

At some point at a later time, I check that the user is a `PowerUser`:

```
User.Identity.HasRole(UIRoles.PowerUser)
```

This works on my local IIS, but once I publish it on a remote IIS machine, it always returns `False` when I try to check if the user is a `PowerUser`. Why could this happen? Am I missing something from, say, the IIS server's configuration or within the remote machine's `web.config`?

Comment: Have you created the roles on the live Database, and is the user a member of those roles? As a test can you point your local web.config at the live database and debug that line of code. (I am assuming that your remote IIS machine is using a separate database)

Comment: @MichaelLake The `web.config` does not point to any database when I run it locally. Is that not supposed to be the case? I thought these roles were just stored inside of the application cookie.

Comment: When using the remote IIS machine - is the Auth cookie present on the client?

Comment: @MichaelLake Yes, it appears to be there, within `All cookies and site data...` in Chrome, and I can also verify that once I authenticate myself the cookie is present using a Cookie Inspector extension.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404935/mvc-5-access-claims-identity-user-data?rq=1

Comment: @MichaelLake I narrowed it down. On the remote machine, I am signing in correctly and the claim is there initially, but I think something is renewing the session cookie and removing the claim at a later point in time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99413/discussion-between-michaellake-and-alexandru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause. It is a bit silly. I was reissuing cookies when I wanted to renew the user's session and the problem was that the `SessionInfo` object I was renewing these cookies to were being replaced with another `SessionInfo` object without any extra claims:

```
session.ToClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

This was wiping the extra claim of `UIRoles.PowerUser` from the original cookie for me.