# asp.net core how to add claims to User

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0, with Azure AD v2.0 endpoint. 
I am getting claims like this:

```
var currentUser = User;

var displayName = currentUser.FindFirst("name").Value;
var claims = currentUser.Claims;
```

I am not used to using this `User` to get claims, but could not get the old way with `System.Security.Claims` to work. So my first question is, is this how I should be getting my claims? And my second question is, how do I add claims to this `User`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> is this how I should be getting my claims?

AFAIK, you could leverage `ControllerBase.HttpContext.User` or `ControllerBase.User` for retrieving the `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` for current user. Details you could follow the similar [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125347/how-to-get-claim-inside-asp-net-core-razor-view).

> And my second question is, how do I add claims to this User?

As you said you are using ASP.NET Core 2.0, with Azure AD v2.0. I assumed that when using `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`, you could add the additional claims under `OnTokenValidated` as follows:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"],
    Authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], "common", "/v2.0"),
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = RemoteFailure,
        OnTokenValidated = TokenValidated
    },
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Instead of using the default validation (validating against
        // a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
        ValidateIssuer = false,

        NameClaimType = "name"
    }
});

private Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    /* ---------------------
    // Replace this with your logic to validate the issuer/tenant
        ---------------------       
    // Retriever caller data from the incoming principal
    string issuer = context.SecurityToken.Issuer;
    string subject = context.SecurityToken.Subject;
    string tenantID = context.Ticket.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

    // Build a dictionary of approved tenants
    IEnumerable<string> approvedTenantIds = new List<string>
    {
        "<Your tenantID>",
        "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad" // MSA Tenant
    };
    o
    if (!approvedTenantIds.Contains(tenantID))
        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
        --------------------- */

    var claimsIdentity=(ClaimsIdentity)context.Ticket.Principal.Identity;
    //add your custom claims here
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test", "helloworld!!!"));

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Then, I used the following code to retrieve the user claims:

```
public IActionResult UserInfo()
{
    return Json(User.Claims.Select(c=>new {type=c.Type,value=c.Value}).ToList());
}
```

**Test:**

[image]

Moreover, you could refer to this sample [Integrating Azure AD (v2.0 endpoint) into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-v2).