# Get data from Claims in Razor Pages Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I store data before logging user in

```
  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginData.Username));
  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginData.Username));
  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Dev"));
  var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
  await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = loginData.RememberMe });
```

Now how can i print role or check?

```
   @Context.User.Claims.Select(c => c.Value)
```

this does not work

Comment: This doesn't work for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125347/how-to-get-claim-inside-asp-net-core-razor-view

Comment: yes this worked