# ASP.NET MVC authentication type Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-identity

I get the current user account ok and manage to remove the domain charters from the output, please see below:

In my HomeController's Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{    
    ViewBag.UserName = User.Identity?.Name;
    return View();
}
```

and from my view

```
<h3>@ViewBag.username.Remove(0, 7)</h3>
```

All works fine, removes the domain name and just displays the users name e.g.  removes corplt/jsmith to just displays "jsmith" -  but can this all be done with in the controller or is it ok to have this code within the view? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

John.

Comment: look to see what other claims are in that `Identity` object

Comment: Do you mean you want to access User.Identity in razor view directly? Maybe you can refer  to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125347/how-to-get-claim-inside-asp-net-core-razor-view).